# How to setup a Servlet based Restlet Webservice with @ApplicationPath?

Tags: maven, tomcat, servlets, jax-rs, restlet

I am trying to run restlet with a tomcat servlet container.

Maven Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

i try to run this without an web.xml. i want to announce my application with the @ApplicationPath annoation but i just get a 404

```
       import org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.JaxRsApplication;  
       import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;  

       @ApplicationPath("rest")
       public class JAXRSConfiguration extends JaxRsApplication {}
```

i know this setup works with jersey